Can Discussions be saved?
There have been discussions about the atrocious state of Discussions and at this point it's hardly worth saving. I understand and share the frustration, but, for this post, let's shift our focus and talk about the immediate actions and features necessary to keep Discussions alive (or revive it).
Following a recent chat (mod-only link) with a Community Manager (I'm a Discussions moderator), they've expressed interest in our ideas for improvement. This is their (IMHO, last) chance to make a difference.
So, I'd like to gather feedback from the community to prioritize existing feature requests for Discussions and potentially identify new, high-impact improvements.
My two cents:

API access: First and foremost, we need API access (read/flag). That would significantly help combat spam.

Community editing: Let the community edit discussions. I understand that editing etiquette is different in Discussions, but we still need to edit typos, bad formatting, etc. and handful of users cannot achieve that. This is one of the main reasons that looking at Discussions leaves a bad taste in the mouth.

Downvotes: Bring back downvotes. As I anticipated, and others pointed out on the same thread, removing downvotes have had multiple negative impacts, but most importantly has hampered moderation by making it much harder to spot low quality posts.

Enhanced tooling: We need better moderation tools. Currently, we cannot even search Discussions making it almost impossible to investigate, for example, low-score/unreplied posts. Moreover, the only way to find spam accounts and repeat offenders is to check the activity page on their profile.

Statistics: Adding Discussions to SEDE seems to be the minimum required to allow us making more informed decisions/statements about Discussions.

Transparency: Update us more frequently. Running an experiment and expanding it without providing any meaningful updates is concerning.


Please share your thoughts and suggestions.

No, They cannot; Time to throw the baby (Discussions) out with the bath water.

@SecurityHound Discussions absolutely can be saved. But these problems have existed since discussions were rolled out, have been reiterated N times, and have not been fixed. Discussions won't be saved. It'll hang around as the spam part of the site no one likes until SE decides to quietly or loudly axe it in 6-8. It can be saved, but it won't be.

@Zoe-Savethedatadump - I don’t have the same hope.

@SecurityHound I don't express a hope?  There's a very clear difference between can (i.e. whether there exists a path, which there does; implement features to fix the problems) and won't (i.e. that the path that does exist will not be taken; the features will never be implemented, because that's how SE rolls)

@SecurityHound I have to agree with Zoe. It can be, but most probably won't be. I have cleared 100+ low quality discussions just last night. Everything is ready for them to finaly step up. This is the last call, they can stop half-a**ing it, or wait for it to be too late (as I said great ideas have failed when implemented poorly, Discussions is not even that).

I think you already did a good job in compiling the required fixes, especially the post from Machavity. On top of it, I would like to propose a reputation bar and duplicate closing. Posters should be reasonably reputable and familiar with SO workflow to properly utilize Discussions and drive meaningful idea exchange. Dupe closing is one of my recent observations, from this post and another post from the same user

"we cannot even search Discussions making it almost impossible to investigate, for example, low-score/unreplied posts" just a note on this one - the motivation for Discussions was to apparently capture more fluid and opinion-based material in a searchable for, so others can benefit from it. Well, we can't search them. Recently, I saw one topic asked in Discussions which I am pretty sure was asked and replied to in the past. I can't find it, though. I mean, I could go over every page but I wouldn't call this "searchable".

Honestly, I think it can be, but I think it really needs a restart. Things NEED (if I could stress that word more I would) to be fixed and addressed that the community have raised repeatedly. A lot of the content in discussions at the moment is bad, and persists due to the lack of curation tooling, so starting again so a better™ idea; removing (almost) all of the existing content will hopefully also remove a lot of the clutter/noise. Though I think some of the well received content could be migrated, the lack of downvotes totally skews the definition of "good".

isn't "Discussions" just half a reddit clone? if that isn't done carefully, we'd copy all the social/moderation problems of reddit into this site.

Only marginally related, but how is legit activity on discussions currently? Is the feature still used significantly except for spamming? Do discussion starters actually get useful feedback? Apart from moderating considerations I ask myself if it's worth to be saved. Is there a big enough benefit of having discussions at the moment? Or at least the hope of it. Do we really want the company to invest resources there (even if that is unlikely anyway) or is it better to not waste more of our time on it?

There's maybe a few dozen decent or better discussions, the rest are more or less void of any form of effort... and voting trends don't seem to really point out which ones are which.

Discussions seemed like an interesting feature at first, providing a place for back-and-forth chats on interesting topics related to specific niches (PHP, AWS, etc.), but the way they were implemented left a lot to be desired... Most recently all I've seen are "Q&A discussions" (content that should have been posted to the main site) or worse, straight-up garbage/spam by 1-rep users... I'd have to echo a lot of the other comments. How would it be saved? Is it even worth saving? Should there be barriers to posting (rep)? Will be interesting to see what comes of this post, if anything.

@Zoe-Savethedatadump - disagree re saving discussions, as the premise is simply flawed. You say there's a path to fix it, and maybe there is a path to make it not be the pile of burning garbage it is now, but I don't see a way to truly save it unless you first find a compelling purpose for this feature. Best case with all the proposed changes implemented is that this turns into something like an SO forum with upvotes... which would be better served by deleting the current code and using an actual forum software (ask jeff for a discount on discourse) and still sounds rather useless to me.

I'm not sure who it would be doing the saving, even if this community manager did a stellar proposal, it doesn't fit within the overall roadmap that was shared and I don't think there has been enough community pickup of the feature to help drive it

@ErikA it is already included in the data dump.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution as I said, it's hardly worth saving. Legit activity is almost non-existent. But either it should be turned off or it should be improved, leaving it as-is is not an option imo.

If I had to guess, I'd wager that Discussions had some sort of company-side momentum behind it (team(s) championing it, upper-management push, etc.) that just... dried up and died sometime this year. I can't think of another reason they'd go as far as building a new miniature platform to then abandon it so absolutely; especially when it's clear there's ongoing development in other areas of the site. It's high time for SE to make a decision to genuinely deal with the issues, put it out of its misery, or at the very least shelve it privately until it can get some actual momentum behind it again.

@l4mpi To be clear, I'm not a fan of discussions either, and I personally believe it's a complete waste of time while everything else is on fire. But it can be salvaged if SE took drastic action and got their ducks in a row, but they're too busy throwing money at genAI to take both the short- and long-term action needed for discussions to evolve into anything even vaguely useful. It is, again, technically possible, but I do not see a single world where SE both has the resources, and is willing to invest them into both discussions and the rest of the public Q&A.

Also, I have at no point said discussions should be saved; I've simply said it could be, if SE actually took the time to sort out the enormous number of problems, which it was clear even before discussions was built that they weren't going to do. It is possible for discussions to be saved, but the discussion of whether it should is a completely different discussion that I didn't comment on in either of my previous comments. The discussion of whether it will is, realistically, just "no".

@M-- "leaving it as-is is not an option imo" I think that without company action (and that's very likely) it simply is the only option. I would just ignore it and not throw your valuable time into it and clean up without proper support. I would just leave it as a spam target and and hope and keep my fingers crossed that nobody with a genuine desire to discuss ever gets there. We could simply wait for some time (say a week) for the company to react, then declare it dead and put up a big warning sign "don't use discussions" and then forget about it.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution that's what I've done for the past 2 weeks, but spent couple of hours to clean it up before posting this as a token of good faith. Agreed.

TIL - A "Discussions" feature exists... guess I need to visit SO more often

@scunliffe Ah that's too bad. Now you have to switch from not knowing it exists to pretending it doesn't exist :)

An update on Discussions and its future is long overdue. I would like to offer our apologies to those who have been affected by the spam issues there. We’re working on some near-term solutions, including completing work on Discussions API endpoints for Charcoal usage. I will be following up with Stack Overflow mods and Discussions mods about the details.
I’d also like to offer some thanks. First and foremost to the Discussions mods who have been doing an outstanding job. And to the SO mods who have been helpful in supporting their work. (So that’s a double thanks for Dalija!)
Also, thanks to the users who have been providing well-intentioned votes and flags in Discussions. There are many of you and we see you and appreciate your efforts as well.
Another double (dash) thanks for M-- for writing this question, and to VLAZ, cocomac and Journeyman Geek for the answers already posted. Excellent points made by all, and the mixed/balanced sentiment expressed is shared by the company as well.
There is plenty of potential for the Discussions concept, but we agree it needs some further iteration and/or revamping before that can be fully realized. We’ve got a number of ideas, and we’re getting those in order ahead of discussing them with moderators and the broader community. Please don’t infer anything specific from this answer about what Discussions might be like in a future state. There are many possibilities.
One thing we’re committed to is that Discussions should be a place accessible for newer users, meaning that success in Q&A (i.e. reputation) should not be a requirement for posting in Discussions. But the low barrier for entry introduces other complications, of course. Aside from spam/abuse risks, we are evaluating the value Discussions provides the community, pain points in using the current feature set, and what investment is needed to realize its full potential.

Considering your first paragraph, should this be updated to [tag:status-planned]?

@M-- I updated cocomac's older post to status-planned. My feeling is that the scope of this post is too broad for a status tag. I can't necessarily say we plan to "save" Discussions in its current form. But the conversation here is an important step.

The take away from this whole experiment ought to be that the company can't just rely on volunteers and software written by volunteers to protect the company's products. For the same reason as why employed nurses at a hospital department can't just all go home and leave everything to non-paid volunteers who don't have training nor access to journals, medicine and so on. And not even answer the phone when the volunteers call for help.

I wonder if there is any even tentative timeline for the immediate actions? Not that in say half a year the situation is essential still the same. The mods doing the outstanding job of saving discussions shouldn't do it for longer than strictly necessary.

Yeah it's hard to actually hold a discussion. The design of it is still so close to the Q&A structure that it takes on a mailing list format, really. Except without the ability to properly respond to a response. Is "Discussions" the right name for what is intended to be achieved with it, I wonder? I get the feeling that new visitors are actually the target audience. I am going to go on a limb here and claim that the intended purpose of it is a reboot of tutoring, but that word has become dirty.

All of these problems stem from a flawed approach for implementing the feature. Here is what the plan by the company seems to be:

Provide an MVP for the feature.
Release it.
Wait for it to be used for a while.
Create new features and take new decisions based on usage patterns that emerge.

On paper, it is a sound plan - you do not need to try and guess what the users would want from the feature. Thus you do not need to spend effort on creating potentially unneeded or otherwise unsuitable features, nor try to plan anything that might turn out to be unrealistic.
However, in practice it is missing crucial things.
First - in practice, it is not saved effort: we, the community, have had to spend our own time on this. We have been handed something we never really wanted and to top it off, it is essentially a proof of concept that we, the community, are also supposed to look after and success or failure of it, depends on us.
So, not only were we not thrilled by Discussions as a start, we still have to look after it. And having to maintain it does not really endear us to Discussions.
What can we take from this: if you want to save developer time on releasing the feature, there is still time lost on the user side of things.
Second, the strategy might have been better of there were any improvements that were done to Discussions. There is no need to guess what to implement, though, there are certainly core features that just are not in the core of it. Here is a statement by staff member Sasha on why Discussions is different to chat:

Our current Chat tool does not easily facilitate extended lifespans of particular conversations, and previous conversations are often hard to find.

Hard to find indeed. But in Discussions, past topics are impossible to find. There is no way to search them. At least I can search in chat.
The statement is from August 2023, so there has been quite enough time to do anything about discoverability. Be it search or anything else (leaving open for other possible implementations that can surface relevant Discussions).
What can we take from this: even when starting with a minimal set of features, they can be expanded with general all-purpose features. Like searching.

As has been argued a few times, I think [so]'s definition of an "MVP" is very different to the community's. Most users would never describe what was initially launched (and even what we have now) is close to an MVP.

@ThomA I don't disagree. I'm just pointing out the basic flow the company goes for and why it fails. It's certainly possible to release a bare-bones MVP and build it up. Release early, release often. But that's...rarely what happens. We usually get a half-baked feature, some improvements here and there for it and then nothing. The last change for Discussions was removing the downvotes. And before that... uh, it was released site-wide. The site-wide release happened in February. Sure, it's labelled "beta" but there should be some movement in betas.

"...some improvements here and there for it and then nothing..." I wonder what the business related term for this behavior is but for humans I'd say it's missing persistence/endurance and maybe also procrastination, i.e. starting many things but almost never finishing any of them.

"On paper, it is a sound plan - you do not need to try and guess what the users would want from the feature" -- why am I suddenly reminded of the "Documentations" project? Yeesh.

@AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні you're not alone; I did remind them about Documentation early on.

As of late Friday, Dec 7th, 2024, temporary fixes/workarounds have been implemented to combat the influx of spam in Discussions (quoting CMs from a private chatroom):

... the rep required to post in Discussions is now 2
A few notes -- the "start discussion" button still shows for 1 rep users. But it will do nothing when clicked. 1 rep users don't see a reply text box when on a Discussion post, nor do they see a reply button on any existing replies.
They can still flag a discussion or reply. They can still vote.

Moreover:

A Discussions read API endpoint is now available to site mods, though this is mainly for Charcoal to play with ...

Again, please note that the increased reputation is not considered to be the permanent solution and numerous options including turning off Discussions everywhere are still considered. That said, I can confirm that we have not encountered any new spam in Discussions since this change.

That’s good news! Even if it’s not as robust as what we’re looking for, even these small measures are a meaningful improvement over nothing.

While I personally believe discussions should go along with AnswerBot to the trashcan, this is definetly a step in the right direction. One thing I'm concerned about it confused 1 rep users wondering why a button randomly does nothing now...

While it's good the quotes are in blockquote format, attribution to the source is still needed.

@Makyen I can do mod-only links. Does that suffice?

@MDoubleDash It would certainly be an improvement. You should also state who the author is. Basically, the referencing requirements, plus, assuming CC BY-SA, based on you saying mod-only links, the additional required by CC BY-SA (my take on CC BY-SA 3.0).

What a clencher this has become. What are the spammers going to do to get that one reputation point needed to circumvent this? I'm genuinely intrigued to find out. IMO... 20 points would have been more future-proof.

@Gimby we're not looking for future-proof, this is temporary anyway. But I should say, I have way more trust in laziness than you do :)

API access
Not sure if you're implying it, but to be safe... I think Charcoal would want a websocket too and not just a API endpoint as Makyen describes in this post. That said, this isn't an area of Charcoal I'm very familiar with & I'll defer to other people here. I'd also highlight this by Machavity.

Charcoal can't even consider a fix here without an API feed of Discussions. I cannot speak for the Charcoal folks about if/when they would be able to scan Discussions, but I'd like to at least see this roadblock removed.

Not saying it won't happen, but if API endpoints & a websocket are added for Discussions, I'd suggest a CM or whoever is leading it gets in touch with someone from Charcoal for the best way to do it and, as Machavity said, when/if it would happen.
Edits and other moderation tools
Agreed on edits. Discussions could be a space to try a different system for edit privileges. As Spevacus touches on here in a more general context, SE could do something like if you have (>2,000 rep) or (>? helpful edits and > ?% approved), you get full edit permissions in Discussions.
Delete votes
I don't know if this would be popular with SE, Inc., but enabling ordinary (non-diamond, non-Discussions mod) users to cast delete votes to remove bad Discussions could help quite a bit. There is a risk that too much gets deleted though, but obviously not enough getting deleted is a problem too.

I have serious concerns about abuse of delete votes, but it was something that crossed my mind too. I feel like having flagging is enough at this stage? I dunno. I'm not a discussions mod so I don't have visibility into how much load there is there. I also don't monitor discussions so I don't really know how bad things are.

Being able to police this cesspool via automation (by Charcoal and others) is a different beast from making it be not a cesspool of low-quality content in the first place. Unless other more fundamental problems with Discussions can be solved, I don't think the community will want to keep it, and it will dilute the resources of Charcoal from the core mission.

The first inclination I have is - perhaps it needs a reset if it was to be saved. I also feel like there's a few practical goals that need to be considered.

I get the impression that Discussions supports the Collectives feature to an extent. From a purely commercial perspective, is Discussions enough of a unique selling point for Collectives, and does the return on resource/finance investment make sense?

From a community perspective, how is it taking up, and what sort of users use Discussions? I think reputation levels are a decent abstraction here. Are Discussions users also active on public Q&A?

Does the content on Discussions add to or distract from the primary Q&A site?

Looking back historically, Discussions feels very similar to Not Programming Related - which became programmers.se later. I feel there's very clear parallels, and from this - does this contribute to users staying and engaging on the content, and producing worthwhile content?


Critically - what is Discussions?
We have a first place (the main site), a second place (meta for talking about the main site), and while the company often gets confused by its existence, chat does cover both general topics, and people often start rooms for specific ones. While SE was designed specifically not to be a forum, Discussions feels more like an image board format? As a experienced SE user, I'm not entirely sure where it fits into my day-to-day use of the platform.
If the 4 questions above have a clear answer and there's clarity over how it fits in, perhaps Discussions can do with a reset, some maintenance, and guidance and try again.
I don't think it's doing that well, from a semi-outsider's perspective, to the point of 'saving' what's there in its current form, and even if so, it needs a pretty substantial cleanup and scope re-examination.
As an aside, as an avid chat user, I take some degree of umbrage that "chat is hard to search" - least on one of my chats, folks used to (and still refer to) things like old PC builds they did and mentioned there years ago . Discussions feels like it lacks both search and structure in comparison to chat.

"Critically - what is Discussions?" - A silly practically abandoned beta feature that for some reason invokes the most powerful "Someone is wrong on the internet!" reaction I have ever seen. We're coming together as a community because of it.

Just to be clear, I was never a fan of Discussions :)

I tried to keep that particular rant short. I think its one of the two things most of the staff who deal with might be a little tired of me ranting about. I think they know what I think, and I'll have plenty to say if chat actually gets picked up again.

Great points here, and excellent questions posed. I can offer some clarification on the first one. Collectives was the starting point and testing ground for Discussions, but Discussions was not meant to support Collectives in any commercial sense. They are separate products, and I see Discussions as a different approach to the "subcommunity" concept. Not focused by topic (like an SE site or Collective) but by interest in a specific type of interaction.

I'm coming in a little blind with respect to discussions - I got nerdsniped by conversations elsewhere but design-wise I'm skeptical that discussions and collectives are separate products. It might be them being around the same age but there's a lot of obvious integration for collectives in discussions. I see at least 2 'unique' links from 'main' discussions to collectives on the top half of the page, and its pretty prominent. vertaintly or advertantly, they feel like parts of the 'same' product.

@JourneymanGeek Fair point. They are certainly still intertwined to a degree. But I'm not trying to dance between semantic raindrops or anything like that. We consider them separate products and their futures will be charted separately.

"What is Discussions" - The trashcan.

Well yes, but I was trying to be constructive. And trashcans have a clear definition of what its meant to do, and every trashcan has a clear purpose. It isn't particularly good as a trashcan either
