A proposal to stop curating/moderating Discussions until it's "fixed"
Discussions has got a lot of attention recently, none of it good. The volume of spam in the area is at an all-time high, which isn't disappearing quickly due to the lack of the usual tools.
This is compounded by the tiny volume of good quality posts in Discussions, meaning that people don't want to visit the area of the site; it's filled with low quality content and spam. The last "good" post (not deleted due to being "not suitable for Discussions") was created five days ago on the 15th, and the last upvoted way back on the 13th. Many of the non-spam posts I have seen in the last week have been simple code dumps, or just entire nonsense.
The community has tried the way they are supposed to with constructive feedback and feature requests on Meta; NONE of the features are implemented. If Stack Overflow aren't interested, then neither should the community be.
In an attempt to get Stack Overflow to do something, I am therefore proposing that as a community we stop curating and moderating Discussions; leave Spam in situ, leave code dumps alone, basically, don't visit the area apart from to watch it burn. Until Stack Overflow actually start doing something, not just acknowledging the problems but start fixing them that we, as a community, stop doing the things that they need us to do (within Discussions); curate & moderate.

To list a few expectations for Discussions, which I feel are musts:

API or WebSocket access, minimally at least for Charcoal so spam can be quickly combatted
Flag history for users. Moderators cannot tell us why a flag would be declined, for example, making their job harder for repeat incorrect flags
Community Edits; Some posts can be saved by other users, we should not rely on mods to fix them.
Downvotes.
Data appears in SEDE.
Moderator tooling improvements (A moderator for the area would be better posting an answer on how these can be improved)
Better onboarding or a reputation increase to post

This is important in my view; it'll help combat spam and the high volume of low quality content. The reputation doesn't need to be high (5 would be fine).
Otherwise we need a SG like area for Discussions, which considering the volume posted, would likely be very manageable.



Feel free to post answers if you disagree with any of these expectations, or want to add to them.
Alternatively, Stack Overflow could turn it off; that would "solve" the problem. If they want to then release it again in the future, then it should still minimally have all the features listed above.

Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/432250/5515060

Yeah that's great, but even if literally everyone on meta agrees it won't make a difference. Meta does not represent Stack Overflow.

It doesn't, but the majority of active curators at least do. @Gimby . It might only mean that things like spam take even longer to disappear, while really low quality stuff hangs around if (Dicussion) Moderators choose to participate, but the area of the site hasn't improved after the community has taken the "right" actions, so inaction seems like the "logical" next step.

I'm absolutely stunned that they haven't pulled the plug on, or at VERY LEAST frozen discussions, yet. The feature is absolutely flooded with spam. Any half-competent product owner would be absolutely scrambling to at least stop that flood... What on earth is going on that they're just ignoring this?!

I've already given up flagging spam in Discussions weeks ago. 2 days ago, after seeing a bigger clean-up effort by a discussion moderator, I flagged 3 posts "not suitable for discussions", but aside from that I gave up and also hope that the SE management will  wake up when the trash doesn't go away quickly anymore.

I 100% support this.

I would propose to go one step further and refuse to use it entirely. It is almost made useless anyway thanks to the incredibly low quality of content. We could also stop participating in any guinea pig "user feedback" experiments advertised by the company since they 1) don't want to hear feedback which isn't in line with what they intended and 2) don't want to hear any feedback at all.

Honestly, if the curation/moderation stops, participation on legimate, on-topic, well written posts would be more or less impossible anyway, @Lundin ; the posts will fall off the front page very quickly. It took less than an hour for the front page (of 15 posts) to all be spam posts.

@Cerbrus My guess is that whoever was in charge of this was fired during the lay-offs and they have nobody left in the company that knows how to deal with it. I would not assume that there are product owners employed by the company, let alone half-competent ones.

I've visited Discussions only a handful of times in the last months. Didn't appeal to me. I wouldn't miss it if it wasn't there.

I find it astonishing that the company was able to outsource anti-spam measures to volunteers. That's crazy. They monetize the platform and thus they should prevent and remove spam. Quitely ignore Discussions like everybody else does.

This could be an answer under my recent question. I wanted to gather everything in once place for the CMs. Anyways, feel free to post an answer with, at least, your suggestions under that posts.

I doubt an answer would have had the desired effect, @M-- . The "Question" is a call to action; an answer wouldn't achieve that on its own, and it would be impossible for it to appear in the "Hot Meta Posts" section.

@ThomA ignore the first part of my comment. I have read your question really fast, but upon looking at it in details (and seeing the edit history), I understand your objective better. Yet, I think listing your few expectations as an answer on that post wouldn't hurt. Cheers.

I'm doing my part by continuing to not visit or use a feature no one asked for.

TIL that there is a "Discussion" part on this website. It's so irrelevant that I don't know it exists

Yup spam needs to be fixed. Today I saw a post advertising a concert in Nashville

So day 1 after proposing this to the very tiny group of people on meta (and I'm doing my part just for the sake of the experiment, I'm not flagging) - all spam gone. Which is not a stretch because there are almost no new legit discussions started, moderators can easily see by themselves that the last X posts are trash and nuke them, flagging not even needed right now I would say.

@Gimby What is really need is for the discussion mods to join the strike. I know multiple wont handle NSFD flags. The system is clearly so fragile that a single discussion mod needing to take a very quick break caused a massive backlog of flags in discussions.

Oh wow, I've never actually clicked into discussions before so I had a look. This is so bad, that I would recommend completely disabling the entire thing until it's fixed. Of the first 15 listed, maybe 2 were not spam/porn bots.I'm actually stunned as to how bad this is.

Fully agree with this proposal, in fact I've advocated for the same thing last month in a similar discussion. Not sure why anyone would continue to do free volunteer work for SE at this point in time.

@Lundin: It was moreso that the effort was insufficiently staffed to begin with (as far as curation goes, it was basically 1-2 CMs primarily handling Collectives stuff and then I was also helping in addition to my other work. And given the lack of tooling on that part of the platform, there was only so much we could do. It's unfortunate that not much progress has been made on the tooling side of things. (It's not clear to me why the company decided to "reinvent the wheel" in that regard instead of carrying over some of the existing tooling there...)

@Starship-OnDiscussionsStrike yes but it is monumental wishful thinking that the moderators even look here. Meta is not that place anymore. Day 2: zero spam or other weird posts.

@Gimby there was (a lot) of spam earlier this morning (UTC). Though it might not be moderators; 3 spam flags also cause removal of the post. This might explain why the spam is going, but not the garbage.

@ThomA In all fairness, as a non-SME, it's not immediately apparent to me why that question should be considered "garbage".

The code dump, or the SQL question, @F1Krazy ? The code dump because it's a code dump, not a discussion. The SQL question because it's not a discussion, it's a question (which likely isn't appropriate for [so] either and probably best asked on [dba.se]).

@F1Krazy I guess you actually do know. We can describe it as a "question" if we stretch the definition a bit. But you didn't use the term "discussion" to describe it. Nor do I believe you are likely to (unless you refer to the feature, not the content of it).

@ThomA The SQL question (which you're spot on about). I didn't actually notice that you'd linked to two different questions there and didn't even see the code dump (which is immediately apparent as garbage).

@F1Krazy FWIW, I also didn't notice it was two links. I only opened the code dump...

@RyanM You unfeatured this post and added a link in the edit note to a chat message that none of us can see. Can you summarise why you did it here?

@DavidG The note in the edit history is self-explanatory. The link will only work for moderators and CMs.

I wouldn't say its clear, the only conclusion I can come up with is that CM's have said theres nothing they can do about it and its going to make SO look bad having the title of this show up on the shiny new homepage. I'd have expected this would have warranted at least some kind of response

@Sayse The edit comment doesn't appear to say that CMs had anything to do with it. Thus, you shouldn't think that they did. If they did, the edit comment would have said so.

@Makyen - Fair enough, I'd based on that they were mentioned in your previous comment and didn't go back to reread the edit note.

@Makyen "the note in the edit history is self-explanatory" - no it isn't, it only explains that mods decided it should not be featured, but not why you came to that conclusion. I'd be interested in the reasoning behind that, right now for the uninitiated it reads like "mods said no" (insert "computer says no" meme here).

@l4mpi that is what the note reads. If mods felt they needed to explain their reasoning to the public, surely they would have done so. I personally don't see much of a need for mods to explain their discussion. However, I don't even see a very compelling reason for this to be featured, hence why I don't see a need to find the reasoning behind unfeaturing it. It's in the HMP anyway, so it's already visible.

@VLAZ my HMP section (main and meta sidebars) only has Thoms "AI questions" post since this morning. Not sure if other users see other post, but from my pov featuring for visibility could be valuable. And re "if mods felt the need" - I feel the need to understand decisions made by mods, and don't see why the reasons behind them should be private, as transparency should be the default for mod actions and exceptions only made when required e.g. if PII is involved. And to be clear I don't suspect any conspiracy here, but it's not "self-explanatory" either and I would welcome an explanation.

The biggest reason why we're not giving a specific reason is very boring: we didn't explicitly agree on any specific reason.  I could hypothetically enumerate every reason that was brought up (some were raised), but it wouldn't necessarily represent the thinking of a majority or even a plurality of the moderators involved in the discussion, and so I'm disinclined to do so in order to avoid painting a potentially misleading picture of why the decision was reached.  The only thing we explicitly agreed on was that it shouldn't be featured.  Once that consensus was clear, I removed the tag.

Discussions is no longer safe for work. And this is not a metaphor. I would shudder to think what a colleague would think if they saw me visiting a page that has a bunch of advertisements for porn.
Since the Discussions feature was expanded to all tags in February 2024, I have been visiting to monitor for spam and report it in CharcoalHQ as well as try and flag anything else I notice which is not spam.
What I have been doing has been an extreme waste of time. There is more spam nowadays (on average) than months ago. Moreover, none of my effort is sustainable. I have been adding more rules to SmokeDetector so it can recognise this spam in the future but extremely few of these rules are hit, since only the main sites and Staging Ground are scanned automatically. We get a lot of repeated spam in Discussions that only shows up in Discussions. That will never be caught while there is no API access to Discussions for SmokeDetector to use.
I am on board with this proposal. Effective immediately, I will no longer visit Discussions.

Your absence is already working. chuckles

Looks like they're all gone now, @Lino . :(

@Lino Oh wow, didn't realize the spam was that bad. I'd only seen various devblog self-promos and even those were enough to turn me off of the feature

If only Discussion was actually a spam honeypot so that spammers spammed less on the main Q&A site... (wishful thinking)

@ThomA no worries, they will come back soon enough. :)

Yeah, I've noticed that 09:00-14:00 UTC seems to be a peak time; I wouldn't be surprised if it's due to the post being made by bots on compromised PCs and those devices are on during those times (perhaps an evening in a certain part of the world).

Holy shit. The latest post is actual porn spam, and it's been up for 20 minutes. Smoke Detector would have had it removed in literal seconds. This is horribly unprofessional, and bad for the brand. Why is this active?!

@JeremyBanks the porn spam has been going for over two weeks now. That's why I said it's NSFW. I was getting increasingly nervous trying to open Discussions at work to try and purge that spam daily. For there would be usually at least  6-10 of these at different times throughout a day.

Spam posts remain up for hours. Right now there are at least 30. I have flagged several similar posts before, but I cannot be bothered anymore.
